# Can't check instance variable values in static method in Eclipse debugger

Tags: java, debugging, static-methods

I want to keep track of values of an instance variable, and my breakpoint starts at a static method. I can't check the instance variable value. Is there a way to do that? I searched over google, but found no clue.

Is it because instance can't be accessed in a static method?

Comment: Static methods aren't associated with instances.

Comment: Please post your code here so that we can suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the variable that you are tracking into the method. Although you just make a note every time you do this so you can remove it when you are done testing.

But honestly, if you don't have access to the variable from within the method, then it probably won't change by the time you have exited the method, unless you have multiple threads. Therefore, you can set the breakpoint after/before the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

A static method cannot access the value of an instance variable, which, by definition, is undefined until an instance of the object is created.

```
public class A {

  private int b;

  public static void foo() {
    b = 1;
  }
}
```

Will not compile for this very reason. A work around it to make b itself static. Of course, you should understand what making b static means. It means that there is exactly one instance of b no matter how many instances of the class exist within a given JVM.